# How to delete a symlinked file

Tags: bash

I want to delete a symlinked file not the symlink.

I'm running a shell script to take mysql backup's in the server and the latest backup date is symlinked to a file called latest.sql and when I try rm -rf latest.sql the symlink is get deleted not the file. Is it possible to delete the particular symliked file and the symlink?.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried to find a solution yourself? what did you do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be

```
rm "$(readlink linkname)"
```

to remove the file the link points to. The link will remain as a dangling link, so use

```
rm "$(readlink linkname)" linkname
```

to remove both. If multiple indirection is a concern, consult `man readlink` for the `-f` andd `-e` options.